# Problem Updating/Installing Java

Tags: java, java-applet

I've had Java installed on my computer for a while. However lately, whenever I go to a website which has got a java applet in it, i only see a white box where the applet previously used to run (this is happening on multiple sites, not just one).

I figured I might have to download java again, so I went to [this page](http://java.com/en/download/chrome.jsp?locale=en&host=java.com) and downloaded the installer:
[image]

However, each time the installer finishes downloading whatever it needs to, I get the error: 
'Uncompression of downloaded file failed':

[image]

What shall I do?

I'm using Windows XP, and I'm still able to run Netbeans on the computer, the problem seems to only be with applets, and occurs in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to download the latest Java bundle [directly](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/) without a download manager and install it the usual way.